# How to run background php process on MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp, background-process

I'm trying to trigger a background php process on MAMP with this code:

```
exec("php /Users/Joe/sandbox/getnew.php?artist=".$artistID." > error_log &");
```

or:

```
shell_exec("nohup /usr/bin/php /Users/Joe/sandbox/getnew.php?artist=".$artistID." > error_log &");
```

It doesn't seem to trigger even with the direct path to the php file? When it is triggered it will collect some information from an API and write it to a database.

Comment: how about with flag `php -f getnew.php`?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either! but thanks for your suggestion Artjom :)

Comment: does your script have execution rights?
anything in logs?

Comment: does it work when you execute it in the cli?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your replies. I'm getting nothing in the error logs - Damian - what's the CLI?

Comment: ah command line- i'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do something like:

```
exec("php /Users/Joe/sandbox/getnew.php?artist=".$artistID, $output);
```

and after:

```
file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $output), FILE_APPEND)
```